# java instrumentation threading model

Tags: java, multithreading, instrumentation

I am curious about how the the java instrumentation process works in the context of multiple threads; more specifically if the main thread of an application submits a ClassTransformer to the JVM via:

> intrumentation.addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer transformer)

then proceeds to create a number of other threads before exiting, my question is:

1)which of the remaining threads are selected to receive the callback form the instrumentation framework to transform the code?

2)Does the JVM have its own execution thread which it uses to transform code via the supplied ClassFileTransformer?

Comment: Figured this out so thought I'd post back to aid other members:          It turns out that the Class transformation process can only be triggered as a result of some thread attempting to instantiate a new class. As a result the JVM will transform the class and return it to THAT thread when it attempts to instantiate a class in the usual way.